# How to close/dismiss default_popup when clicked outside in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, browser-action

I know that we can close a `default_popup` using `window.close()` but i need to close the popup when user taps on outside. I was not able to get any documentation about it in the console.

```
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"auth_popup.html"
},
```

Comment: The popup is closed automatically when the user clicks the browser window outside of the popup. If you want to detect a click outside of the *entire browser window* you can try using [chrome.windows.onFocusChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onFocusChanged) listener.

Comment: No it's not dismissing when I click outside the popup, however it get dismiss when I execute window.close on a button inside popup

Comment: In that case it must be OS-specific behavior as it works as noted in Windows. If chrome.windows.onFocusChanged approach won't work for this case then the only solution would be to write a separate utility to monitor system-wide mouse clicks and invoke it via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging.html).

Comment: The popup will not close automatically if you have the dev tools open.